# Xfce - Docky & Thunar - Missing icon

Tags: 12.04, xfce, docky, thunar

Im using xfce in combination with docky. But when I start Thunar via the Filemanager-icon it opens (ofc) Thunar, but it has a wrong icon (on the very right)
How to fix that? Normally, the file manager icon should just be highlighted after starting a new program (like with Firefox.)

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found a solution. Was just a missing file. Do a

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/Thunar.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

and the Problem should be resolved.

But one problem remains: Thunar remains twice in the docky-panel.

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/xfce4-terminal.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

For the terminal.

Comment: To solve double icons problem: discard the old icon by dragging it off from Docky, right click the new one and "Pin to Dock".

Answer (score 3):

I used wegsehen's idea and copied all the desktop files to the .local. Then I removed all docky icons and added them from the .local and that fixed the double icon problem for me.

I copied all .desktop files to the ~/.local/share/applications

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/* ~/.local/share/applications
```

Then I removed for example the Thunar shortcut from docky and added it again, but now from ~/.local/share/applications (dragging it over worked)
You can do that to any other icon you want in docky

Answer (score 1):

```
ln -s /usr/share/applications ~/.local/share/applications
```

I made link for all applications.