# Missing Application Entry (Thunar) in Xubuntu-Desktop

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, appmenu

I have Xubuntu-Desktop installed over Ubuntu, and Thunar File Manager is installed by default.

However, it does not show up as an application in any of my searches. I can run it by typing thunar in the the terminal.

**This is a problem because Docky (my dock application) does not detect Thunar.**

Here are some screenshots:

Thunar Does not show up:

[image: Thunar Does not show up]

Only the option to 'run thunar' shows up:
[image: Only the option to run thunar shows up]

Thunar does not show up in applications list:
[image: Thunar does not show up in applications list]

I know for a fact that thunar is installed:
[image: Thunar is installed]

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling thunar. Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Edit:
I found a solution for anyone that sees this in the future:**

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/Thunar.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

**Answer is from here: [Xfce - Docky & Thunar - Missing icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163898/xfce-docky-thunar-missing-icon/735644)**

Comment: Some DEsktops call apps by their name (eg. Thunar), others list them in menus by what the do (File Manager).  This is just a difference, and **not** a problem needing fix.   If you're not happy with your menu system, use another one

Comment: Yeah but both 'Files' and 'File Manager' launch nautilus instead of thunar even though thunar is set as my default.

Also other applications like docky don't recognize that thunar exists which means I can't keep it in my dock

Comment: Please [edit], add the answer as second post below removing it from the question and accept the answer that helped you most by clicking the tick left to it.

Answer (score 0):

The `File Manager` listing in the Appfinder menu is associated to the `exo-preferred-applications` settings so it opens whatever the default is set to.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and in the run box type in `exo-preferred-applications`.

[image]

Then click on Launch.

Go to the Utilities Tab then in `File Manager` choose `Thunar`.  Then close the application.

[image]

Now, every time you open that `File Manager` it will launch `Thunar`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I already found the solution using a different method (I edited my post to include the answer). I don't know if this would have worked but it will hopefully be useful for people who view this thread in the future