# Why one Thunar folder doesn't show icons as in the other one?

Tags: xubuntu, icons, .desktop, thunar-custom-actions

I've been trying to solve Docky not showing Xfce and Thunar icons, and did with the help of [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163898/xfce-docky-thunar-missing-icon/735644).

However in the process of it I started wondering, why these two folders (`/usr/share/applications/` and `~/.local/share/applications/`) are showing file icons differently?
[image: screenshot]

I've not found any setting in Thunar options regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder `/usr/share/applications` is handled in a special way and the icons displayed for a `.desktop`-file are defined in the `.desktop`-file itself. If you take a deeper look you will see that Thunar also does not display the real file names in `/usr/share/applications` but an alias which is also defined in the `.desktop`-file.

For the folder `~/local/share/applications` all this is not the case, Thunar displays the real file names and the default icons for the different file types.

The question [Can Nautilus display a .desktop file by its real name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17220/can-nautilus-display-a-desktop-file-by-its-real-name/915740#915740) is heavily related, at least regarding the displayed file names.

**Trick with soft-link:**

If you want to display the files in `~/.local/share/applications` in the same way as files are displayed in `/usr/share/applications`, you could do it with a soft-link placed in `/usr/share` which points to `~/.local/share/applications`:

```
sudo ln -s ~/.local/share/applications /usr/share/applicationsinhome
```

Now you can browse in Thunar to `/usr/share/applicationsinhome`. This will display the files located in `~/.local/share/applications` in the same way as the files in `/usr/share/applications` and you would still be able to delete, create or edit files without root-privileges.

Please take a look at my answer in the linked question too, there I explained how to do it the other way around.

Comment: I see. Your answer explains how to make it show real names. Is there a way to make ~/.local/share/applications show stuff in the same way as /usr/share/applications?

Comment: The answers in the linked questions explain how to show real file names in `/usr/share applications`. My answer just explains that the mentioned folders are handled differently by Thunar, it's also the case in Nautilus. For me it doesn't matter, as long as I know what's going on I don't care about how things are going to be displayed. But take a look at my edit please...